# Why @Column(unique = true) does not work?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

I have following code:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "LOGIN", unique = true)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "ROLE")
    private UserRole role;

    @Column(name = "E_MAIL", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Convert(converter = UserStrategyConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "STRATEGY")
    private UserStrategy userStrategy;

    @Column(name = "SUBSCRIPTION")
    private Boolean subscription;

    @Column(name = "MONEY")
    private BigDecimal money;
```

My problem: When I put this object from postman in json:

```
{
    "firstName": "Daniel",
    "lastName": "xxx",

    "password": "daniel",
    "role": "ROLE_USER",
    "email": "test@test.pl",
    "subscription": false,
    "money": "1200"
}
```

It create object in entity. Problem is because I can multiply this object again and again instead of `unique = true` in columns (`email` and `login`). Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Does the following work? `@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "login"), @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email") })`, not sure if the `columnNames` must be the names from the java-entity or from the table, you'd have to try that out

Comment: It doesnt work for me too :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate will take into account the constraint `unique = true` only at the time of [schema generation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation).

During schema generation the following constraint will be added:

```sql
alter table User
add constraint UK_u31e1frmjp9mxf8k8tmp990i unique (email)
```

If you do not use the schema generation there is no sense of using `unique = true`.

Comment: How can you tell if schema generation is being used?